# Chromium throws NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, chromium

Started working today and Chromium on Ubuntu suddenly throws

```
NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED on a well known host.
```

Already tried deleting `.pki/nssdb/*`, but nothing changed.

Comment: so deinstalling chromium and restarting ubuntu and installing chromium again worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

I have the same problem. This is what I found out so far:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664177
https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=ALERT2160

Are you also using Version 53.0.2785.143?

Looks like it is important when the build happened: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/cert/ct_policy_enforcer.cc#44

Looks like the best workaround is to upgrade to 54.x, wait for a patch or use another browser.

**Update:** A new version of chromium, that fixes the problem, was just released [(at least for ubuntu)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380/comments/44).

Comment: I'm using version 53.0.2785.143

Comment: Where can I find version 54?

Answer (score 6):

quick tip: set system date a few days back

Comment: Amazing this worked, even after I'd set the date back to the correct date.https://stackoverflow.com/users/7157744/occ could you explain why this works please?

Comment: This purely fixes the problem. Also it didn't last after changing the cert back.

Comment: I deleted my version of chromium using the software center and reinstalled. This appears to have fixed the problem, at least for now.   The version that's currently installed is  53.0.2785.143

Comment: Fascinating tip, but not really a practical solution.